# Error Message: Call to a member function getSheetByName() on null ON exporting multiple sheet on single click

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have tried to export multiple sheets on single button click and saved the files in the directory on the same server. But the error given on the same.
Here is my code -

$URL = APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once($URL);

```
        foreach($users as $row){
            $username = $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'];
            $userid = $row['userid']; 
            
            $object = new PHPExcel();
            
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', '#');
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'status');
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Name');
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'startdatetime');
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'enddatetime');
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', 'clientname');
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1', 'productname');
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1', 'projectname');
            $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1', 'Description');
            
            
            $excel_row = 2;
            $sdate = $this->input->post('sdate');
            $edate = $this->input->post('edate');
            $worklog = $this->Hr_model->selectworklogbyId($sdate, $edate, $userid);
             //echo "<pre>"; print_r($worklog); 
            
            if(count($worklog) > 0){
                $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                foreach($worklog as $rowworklog){
                $desc = removeTags($rowworklog['description'], array('body'));

                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$excel_row, $excel_row-1);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$excel_row, $rowworklog["status"]);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$excel_row, $username);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$excel_row, $rowworklog["startdatetime"]);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$excel_row, $rowworklog["enddatetime"]);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$excel_row, $rowworklog["clientname"]);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$excel_row, $rowworklog["productname"]);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$excel_row, $rowworklog["projectname"]);
                $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$excel_row, $desc);
                $excel_row++;
            }
            //echo "hello".$excel_row; die;
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($TotalTimeArr); 
            
            $month = date('M', strtotime($sdate));
            $file_name = 'Worklog-'.$month.'-'.$username.'.xls';
            //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");   
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
            
            $objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,'assets/excel_files/'.$file_name,__FILE__));
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Files are exported and saved to the directory.');
```

Comment: The write permission is enabled on the destination directory?

Comment: yes, its enabled

Comment: Now you create a new PHPExcel object for each user. Try to move `$object = new PHPExcel();` before to `foreach($users as $row){`.

Comment: And I found 2 sytax error: 1. missing closing brackets of `foreach($users as $row){` and `foreach($worklog as $rowworklog){`